# Generalization of FLT using Binomial Theorem

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to prove that
$$x^{p^{j}} \equiv x^{p^{j-1}} \mod p^{j}$$
for any prime $p$, integer $x$, and natural number $j$.

I'm attempting to do induction. The base case follows from Fermat's Little Theorem. But the inductive step is giving me trouble.

Any advice?

Comment: If $p\not\mid x$ then this is equivalent to $x^{p^{j-1}(p-1)}=(x^{p-1})^{p^{j-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{p^j}$ now by fermat $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ so $x^{p-1}=1+kp$ you're left to prove that $(1+kp)^{p^{j-1}} \equiv 1\pmod{p^j}$ it shouldn't be that hard to prove that each term from binomial expansion is divisible by $p^j$ except $1^{p^{j-1}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious if $p|x$. Hence suppose $p,x$ are coprime. We can argue by induction, and note the base case $j=1$ is essentially Fermat.

We have that $$x^{p^{j}} - x^{p^{j-1}} = (x^{p^{j-1}})^p - (x^{p^{j-2}})^p = (x^{p^{j-1}} - x^{p^{j-2}})\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (x^{p^{j-1}})^{k}(x^{p^{j-2}})^{p-1-k}$$

By induction, $x^{p^{j-1}} - x^{p^{j-2}}$ is divisible by $p^{j-1}$ so it's enough to show the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (x^{p^{j-1}})^{k}(x^{p^{j-2}})^{p-1-k}$ is divisible by $p$.

Note that $$(x^{p^{j-1}})^k(x^{p^{j-2}})^{p-1-k} = x^{(p-1-k)p^{j-2} + p^{j-1}k} = x^{p^{j-2}(p-1-k+pk)} = x^{p^{j-2}(p-1)(1+k)} = (x^{p^{j-2}(1+k)})^{p-1}$$ and this is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ by Fermat. Hence

$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (x^{p^{j-1}})^{k}(x^{p^{j-2}})^{p-1-k} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} 1 \equiv 0 \ \text{mod} \ p$$

as desired.